# Calculated css variables don't update in media queries

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

I've been working with some code that uses css variables where one of the variables derives it's value from a `calc` formula containing another variable (like the code below)

```
:root {
 --parent-size: 20rem;
 --child-size: calc(var(--parent-size) / 2);
}

...

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 --parent-size: 30rem;
}
```

When `var(--parent-size)` change; `var(--child-size)` remains the same. 
I'm assuming this might be a bug as it only affect variables with calculated values.

I've added a jsfiddle for reference [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hjpaLs23/2/)